# Is there any way to submit a FB app for review while it in "Live Mode"?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-fql

so I made a web based FB app. submitted it for review because I need 3 more permissions (not the basic one) for new functions that I want to add in my site (Which is very active).
I submitted it for review 12 days before, and after 10 days I decided to cancel it and re-submit (I thought it's a bug because a year ago a review took no more than 3 days).

Right now i'm still waiting for more than 48 hours already and still nothing.

My site is down because users can't login while the app is in development mode.
I can't continue like that, my site is down for 12 days and I can't keep it down for a whole month, i'll lose all my users. As I said the site is very active, and keeping it down for that long is hurting bad the business.

Is there any way to make the app "Live" but still manage to be approved? Because from what I understood, all apps that request new permissions should stay in Development mode until the review is done because only in this mode the Facebook Checker can access the un-approved permissions, while in Live Mode he will be able to access only the basic ones and then he will just deny my request.

Your thoughts?

I don't think we should harm our businesses like that and shut down our sites for more than 20 days just because the review process is slow. I think Facebook must find a way that sites will be able to be active while the review of the app also will continue and it will not harm it.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming. Did you contact Facebook developer support?

Comment: there is no "Facebook developer support". Only community help. @mustaccio

Comment: Instead complaining about how Facebook’s process hurts your business, you could make an effort to _properly_ inform yourself … First of all, you _can_ submit your app while it is in live mode - you will just not be able to ask any of your app users for any of the permissions you did not get reviewed yet. (The Facebook reviewers have accounts that are not limited by this available for testing. )

Comment: Secondly, the documentation has a section specifically dedicated to submitting live apps for review, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review#app-review-for-live-apps (main recommendation, use a test app for development & review.)

Comment: Hey @misorude , i'm not one of those guys who doesn't do their homework before reaching out to Stackoverflow. I read this multiple times, and it's still not clear enough. Nothing is clear. Because I can use a test app for dev & review, but if my live app is going to be connected to my site and not the test app, how the reviewers will check the test app? But regarding your first answer, about that it doesn't have to stay in dev mode while it's under review. Are you sure? because people who got rejected told me that fb support told them it happened because their app wasn't in dev mode.

Comment: _“but if my live app is going to be connected to my site and not the test app, how the reviewers will check the test app?”_ - well _you_ provide a way for them to test it on your site with your test app id – could be as simple as adding a URL parameter that makes your site use a different app id (and branch into different functionality, if necessary), or you set up a test version on a subdomain, or sth. like that. _“about that it doesn't have to stay in dev mode while it's under review. Are you sure?”_ - why would they have that explicitly covered in their documentation otherwise?

Comment: That's the problem, that my site is built on a very specific system which can use only one app. I can't  "copy" the site or do something like that. So the option of making a test app isn't for me (I think). `why would they have that explicitly covered in their documentation otherwise?` I did not see any sentence in their documentation which explains that "You can get back to live mode once you done making the screencasts and submitted for review"

Answer (score 0):

Oh boy, be careful there. FB app reviewers are not the smartest bunch. My app reviewer went to localhost despite being clearly instructed by text and video to go to the live URL.

So in your case, I would suggest get the site back online and make sure EVERYTHING is in order before submitting your app for review.